# How do I make a one-way trapdoor?

Tags: terraria

I'm working on a mob trap like the one shown [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=05Wfh_Alwac&list=PL-VeuxozZhHulyR04ipoKQphizchQK7ri&index=3), but the slime just jumps out. I have decided to make a one-way trapdoor so that monsters can fall down into it, but it can't jump out. Please note I do *not* want farming techniques, I know this isn't the best, I just want to know how to make a one-way vertical gate.

Comment: If the slimes are able to jump out just build a bigger hole? I'm not sure if you can place pressure plates on top of actuators which would be one way to make a trap door. You can make one using a lever or switch attached to actuators placed above a hole in the ground but it wouldn't something you can leave unattended and hope it works. Just wait till a mob is above the hole then open it up with the lever/switch and close it once they fall in.

Comment: How do you mean build a bigger hole? Like deeper? The whole I was using before I asked this was 5 wide by 20 tall, but it looks like the slime can change jump heights depending on the hole, like with a 14 deep hole it was *only just* getting out, but it was also *only just* getting out of a 20 deep hole. I don't want to make my trap bigger than a screen, as that would just get the way and by that point I might as well use a simpler design. You can't place pressure plates on actuators, and my goal is for this to be fully afk-able. Thanks for your input!

Comment: How far into the game are you?

Comment: Endgame. I've beaten the moon lord and have pretty much everything needed to make traps.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used any exact sciences, but from what I've seen, if you try using slanted blocks and funnel into your hole, the slime will in fact jump in at some points (slime's contact hit box is just under 1x1). This also solves jumping out. Because the slimes jump at an angle, they will have no ability to jump back out, so long as the hole isn't along a wall.

Try something like this:

-\_/\_/\_/\_/-

- is solid
/ is downward left slant
\ is downward right slant
_ is open air

Comment: This makes sense, but then larger mosters wouldn't be able to get through, right? It doesn't matter anyway, I asked this is august 2016.

Answer (score 0):

[image: What I have made]
It looks like two block deep honey stops the slime jumping through it, but mobs still fall through. It's not the most elegant design, but it will work untill I find something more effective. Please feel free to submit better answers though, as I am not fully satisfied with this.

Comment: What do you use under the honey that keeps the honey from dropping but that allows mobs to fall through?  Do the mobs just drop into the honey and then are unable to jump up out of it? Your picture and/or explanation is not very clear.

Comment: That picture is almost impossible to see. It's the middle of the night and you didn't put any torches up... :/

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Sorry about the bad quality picture, I used bubble blocks to keep the honey up. The mobs fall through the honey, they don't get stuck. The honey slows mobs going through it, which doesn't really effect the mobs going down, but the slime loses momentum without actually moving as high as it otherwise would.